# How to use ranges::actions::insert with std::vector

Tags: c++, range-v3

Without ranges inserting element into the vector looks like this: `my_vec.insert(std::begin(my_vec), 0);`

Now I'm trying to do same thing with ranges:

```
#include <range/v3/action/insert.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> input = {-2, 1, -3, 4, -1, 2, 1, -5, 4};
    for (auto x : ranges::actions::insert(input, 0, 0)) {
        std::cout << x << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

And I get a lot of compiler errors looking like this one:

```
lib/range-v3/include/range/v3/action/insert.hpp:243:18: note: candidate template ignored:
    substitution failure [with Rng = std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> > &, I = int, T = int]:
    no matching function for call to 'insert'
        auto operator()(Rng && rng, I p, T && t) const
```

I've also tried `ranges::actions::insert(input, {0, 0})`, because I see following overload:

```
auto operator()(Rng && rng, I p, std::initializer_list<T> rng2)
```

But it still does not work. I'm using clang-9.0.0 and compile with `-std=c++17` flag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, `ranges::actions::insert(cont, pos, value)` essentially calls `cont.insert(pos, value)`, so `pos` should be an iterator, not an integer value.

Second, `ranges::actions::insert` returns [`insert_result_t`](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/blob/3db6ffa4f77496344125afc9fd056bc73cde0632/include/range/v3/action/insert.hpp#L35-L37), which is just the result of the `insert` member function call:

```
template<typename Cont, typename... Args>
using insert_result_t = decltype(
    unwrap_reference(std::declval<Cont>()).insert(std::declval<Args>()...));
```

`std::vector::insert` returns `std::vector::iterator`, which cannot be used with the range-based for.  Iterate over the vector instead:

```
#include <range/v3/action/insert.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> input = {-2, 1, -3, 4, -1, 2, 1, -5, 4};
    ranges::actions::insert(input, input.begin(), 0); // input.begin() instead of 0
    for (auto x : input) {                            // iterate over the vector
        std::cout << x << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

([live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/MMz1r6W8WcuyGcHa))